# Use Laravel package in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, laravel, queue, package

I am trying to use Queue package of Laravel in Symfony 2. Are there are any resources that I can refer to that will help me to use Laravel package in Symfony 2.

Or perhaps some one have any prior experience in this subject that they can share....?

Comment: Questions asking for resources are off-topic on StackOverflow. Besides that, just use the package as if it was used in a standalone project.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at Matt Stauffer's **IlluminateNonLaravel** project, at https://github.com/mattstauffer/IlluminateNonLaravel. In the `public/queue` directory, you'll find a detailed example on using the Laravel queue package in projects outside of Laravel.